# Show & Edit Multiple Rows (MySQL & PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've got an interesting problem that I just can't seem to think around. So let's say I have a database table with 'id', 'name', and 'email'. I need to list each result out of the database in an HTML table. Simple, just do a foreach loop and show them all, but I need to edit each one; maybe change the name on one of them and an email on the other, etc, etc. but then when this super big table/form is submitted, how do I process and update each one? No clue if that even makes sense, but any suggestions would be awesome.

Comment: you need to import the data of the MySQL Table into an HTML table and while loading the table alter some data?

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

- Use AJAX to perform the updates in the background (show a "Save" button when a field is changed/focused then send the row's information off to an ajax page for submission)
- Use JavaScript and a hidden field that's changed on one of the fields' focus event in a row to flag that row has a possible modification
- Use good'ol'fashioned iterating and look for deltas.

Comment: I'd second the iterating+deltas. Easiest one to get done quickly, and will work reliably for all browsers.

Comment: @Fanis: I tend to agree. And if the amount of data is an issue, OP should consider paginating the information in to more manageable chunks and work with it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Save them all to arrays. In the HTML do:

```
<input name="id[]" />
```

etc. And then when you go into PHP do:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $poop) { /* INSERT EACH ROW MYSQL HERE, REFERRING TO THE EMAIL AS $_POST['email'][$key] */ }
```